# Jacobian when representing integral of differential form by Riemann integral?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, differential-forms

In [Terence Tao's note](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~tao/preprints/forms.pdf):

> If $Ω$ is any open bounded domain in $R^n$ , we then have the identity
>   $$\int_Ω f (x)dx_1 ∧ . . . ∧ dx_n = \int_Ω f (x) dx$$
>
> where on the left we have an integral of a differential form (with $Ω$
>   viewed as a positively oriented n-dimensional manifold), and on the
>   right we have the Riemann or Lebesgue integral of $f$ on $Ω$.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_forms#Integration) (basically same as in baby Rudin):

> Let
>
> $$\omega=\sum a_{i_1,\dots,i_k}({\mathbf x})\,dx^{i_1} \wedge \cdots
>  \wedge dx^{i_k} $$
>
> be a differential form and $S$ a differentiable $k$-manifold over
>   which we wish to integrate, where $S$ has the parameterization
>
> $$S({\mathbf u})=(x^1({\mathbf u}),\dots,x^n({\mathbf u}))$$
>
> for $u$ in the parameter domain $D$. Then (Rudin 1976) defines the
>   integral of the differential form over $S$ as
>
> $$\int_S \omega =\int_D \sum a_{i_1,\dots,i_k}(S({\mathbf u}))
>  \frac{\partial(x^{i_1},\dots,x^{i_k})}{\partial(u^{1},\dots,u^{k})}\,du^1\ldots
>  du^k$$
>
> where
>
> $$\frac{\partial(x^{i_1},\dots,x^{i_k})}{\partial(u^{1},\dots,u^{k})}$$
>
> is the determinant of the Jacobian.

1. I wonder if in the case of Wikipedia, the change of variable can be
   eliminated just as in Terence Tao's, for example,

   \begin{align} \int_S \omega  &=\int_D \sum
   a_{i_1,\dots,i_k}(S({\mathbf u})) 
   \frac{\partial(x^{i_1},\dots,x^{i_k})}{\partial(u^{1},\dots,u^{k})}\,du^1\ldots
   du^k \\ &=\int_S \sum a_{i_1,\dots,i_k}(x) \,dx^{i_1}\ldots dx^{i_k}
   ? \end{align}

   If not, when can it be?
2. If the manifold $S$ is not a subset of $R^n$, the Jacobian will not make sense. Can $\int_S \omega $
   still be represented by Riemann/Lebesgue integral? How is that like if yes?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: I tried to use `\begin{align}` to break the last equation into two lines, but it doesn't work. Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: I fixed it up. You have to place three backslashes at the end of each line because of how [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax) does escaping, I think.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most sources will take Tao's "identity" as a definition: $dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$ measures volume in $\mathbf R^n$ in the a way that corresponds to our intuition and previous notions of integration in Euclidean space. It's not clear to me that he's eliminating any "change of variable".

To integrate an $n$-form $\omega$ (let's assume compactly supported so I don't have to worry about convergence) on an $n$-manifold $M$ that is neither (a) embedded in Euclidean space nor (b) parametrized by a single chart, we can do the following. If we first assume that $(U, \varphi)$ is a chart on $M$ containing the support [the points at which the fibre of $\omega$ is non-zero] of $\omega$, then we define
$$
\int_M \omega = \int_{\varphi(U)} (\varphi^{-1})^*\omega
$$
where $(\varphi^{-1})^*\omega$ is the [pullback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_forms#Pullback). The integral on the right is computed via Tao's definition.

In general, we take a finite collection of charts $(U_i, \varphi_i)$ covering the support of $\omega$ and a smooth [partition of unity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_unity) $\{\psi_i\}$ of $M$ subordinate to $\{U_i\}$. Then let
$$
\int_M \omega = \sum_i \int_M \psi_i\omega.
$$
This makes sense, because the support of $\psi_i\omega$ is contained in $U_i$. It is not too hard to show that this definition of $\int_M \omega$ is independent of the many choices we've made. For a better discussion, look in any introduction to manifolds, e.g. [Lee's *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds*](http://www.math.washington.edu/~lee/Books/smooth.html).

**Note.** Here the Jacobian is a coordinate-dependent expression hidden in the pullback. I may write out how this goes later if there is interest and time. Also, I would avoid using this to actually compute $\int_M \omega$. There are other ways of computing (which are less theoretically tidy) which are more efficient.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I am interested in knowing how the Jacobian is a coordinate-dependent expression hidden in the pullback, and some other ways of computing (which are less theoretically tidy) which are more efficient. Really appreciate your time.

Comment: Intuitively $\int_R dx^1 \wedge \cdots \wedge dx^n$ sounds like a definition of a volume, that I evaluate via successive "numerical" integrals $V=\int dx^1...\int dx^n$. But I need to know that I get the same answer in every coordinate frame.

So I rewrite the integrand in terms of some frame $y^b$, and out pops a Jacobian determinant. I integrate again, Jacobian and all, to get some definite scalar $V'$, which I cannot simply define to be $V$.  But how do we prove $V'=V$ (i.e. that Jacobians work) without a circular use of the very definition of volume which we are trying to prove consistent?